# How can I open the scripts/links into a new window?

Tags: javascript, onclick

These bookmarking scripts open in target="_self". How can I open the scripts/links in target="_blank"?

This:

```
<a href="http://www.reddit.com/submit" onclick="window.location = 'http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location); return false"> <img src="http://www.reddit.com/static/spreddit7.gif" alt="submit to reddit" border="0" /> </a>
```

And this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.reddit.com/buttonlite.js?i=1"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `window.open(...)` method

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location));">open window</a>
```

Comment: Thanks,

The first social sharing button opens into a new window now, replacing onclick="window.location..." with "window.open...".

I couldn't find a solution for the second button yet, to open reddit into a new window:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.reddit.com/buttonlite.js?i=1"></script>

Comment: You can create a page in you project (e.g. reddit.html) and open it with `window.open(...)` and the page will load the script in the head...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the context, however you could try to put a target="_blank" attribute into your -tag OR use window.open('http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location)); return false;

I think the second one is your solution.